# Get URL for specific post

Tags: go, hugo

Let's say I have a specific post:

`posts/8-1-2020/index.html`

It has a slug:

`my-post`.

I want to link to this directly from another article. How can I retrieve the URL with Hugo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be what the [shortcode `ref`](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/) is for:

```
{{< ref "/posts/8-1-2020/my-post" >}}
```

> You will get an error if your document could not be uniquely resolved